# "I hear about it more and more these days" or "I am hearing about it more and more this days"?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> **I hear** about the issue more and more these days.
>
> **I am hearing** about the issue more and more these days.

Many will say that it is incorrect to use the word *hear* in the progressive aspect, but I have heard English native speakers use.

Comment: If _hear about X_ is used in the progressive, it refers to successive events of hearing about some one thing; in other words, it's generic. And so is the non-progressive use. Which one is used is the speaker's choice; there's no difference in meaning in this sentence, and both are grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The two tenses are used in different contexts.

**I hear....** is used either in the sense of **people are saying that** or **talking about**, as in your first example.

People also say **I hear you**, meaning that I've taken note of what you are saying.

They might also say **I hear something upstairs** although it's more likely to be **I can hear something upstairs**.

Your second example is NOT idiomatic. But you may well hear native English speakers use it in contexts which refer to the present situation, for example:

> Question: What's the matter?
>   Answer: I am hearing a strange noise.

or:

> There's a problem with my hearing aid and I'm not hearing you very well.

Comment: What about *"I keep hearing about ..."*? That is idiomatic, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is.